# How to use post method for xml data using php

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have a api which sends messages to the people ,and the api in the form of url ,which takes user login details and the phone number as input for the url .At a time a time I am able to send 10 sms ,but I want to implement it for bulk sms .

I am trying this code ,but it's working only for 10sms,if we are providing more than 10 mobile numbers it's not working ,can anyone suggest me what mistake I making in my code

Code:

```
$numbersarray=explode(",",$numbers);    //stores numbers as array

    /*XML API by Aditya*/
    $numbers_xml_string=""; //stores XML string of numbers and message
    foreach($numbersarray as $num){
        $numbers_xml_string.="<Message><To>".$num."</To><Text>".$text."</Text></Message>";
    }
    //XML string to be encoded
    $xmlstring="<SmsQueue><Account><User>".$user."</User><Password>".$password."</Password></Account><MessageData><SenderId>".$api_id."</SenderId><Gwid>1</Gwid><DataCoding>0</DataCoding></MessageData><Messages>".$numbers_xml_string."</Messages></SmsQueue>";

    $xmlstring=urlencode($xmlstring);//encode the string
    //prepare URL
    $url="http://login.smsgatewayhub.com/xmlapi/pushsms.aspx?data=".$xmlstring;
    echo "url".$url;


$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($numbersarray),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: do you solved your problem?

Comment: The limit is not the problem,it's regarding the code ..

Answer (score 0):

There may be two reasons according to your sample code:

First you may only have permissions to send 10 SMS messages.

Second you can only send 10 messages every a certain time. In this case you should know what is the time you should wait and run your script each this time to send sms to the remaining numbers.